# creating RGB color from empty array

Tags: python, opencv, colors, color-picker

I have an array

```
img = cv2.imread("../heatmap.jpg",3)
img = cv2.resize(img,(416,416))
heatmap  = np.zeros_like(img)
```

And now i would like to create RGB colors, accoring to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) 
rgb(255, 26, 26) should be red,

However using something like

```
heatmap[i][j][0]=256
heatmap[i][j][1]=26
heatmap[i][j][2]=26
```

Does not produce red color, it produces blue color, why is this happening? How can i mix color like this then?

Comment: OpenCV `imread`, `imwrite`, `imshow`, etc. use BGR. Read the docs.

Comment: would you mind to link it? I cannot find anything

Comment: Here's a link... https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html Search on that page for "BGR"

Comment: [`imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) "In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order." | [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) "... or 3-channel (with 'BGR' channel order)..."